# Jenkins Plugin for Writing to the Change Log?

Tags: version-control, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone know of a Jenkins plugin which will allow you to easily set your own values for the "Changes" portion of a build?

We're manually performing our own SCM syncs, and so we don't currently have access to or know how to change the "Changes" portion of the build status.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There was a plugin that allowed to populate the contents of "Change Log" from a file... but I can't find it's name. It had almost no description and a bad screenshot in German.

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific plugin to do it.

Each builds change log is saved in a location like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\BuildJobName\builds\2014-09-11_21-30-25\changelog.xml"

You can manually edit it or write an app which edits the changelog.xml

The format of the changelog.xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
    <logentry revision="16349">
        <author>LeoN</author>
        <date>2014-10-24T08:33:57.708042Z</date>
        <paths>
            <path action="M" localPath="Binaries\Plugins\product.wxs" kind="file">/trunk/Project Phases/Development/Binaries/Plugins/product.wxs</path>
            <path action="M or D or A" localPath="LocalPath From repo" kind="dir or File">Svn Path</path>           
        </paths>
        <msg> Fixed Issues.</msg>
    </logentry>
</log>
```

Action attribute can have values such as M,D,A

M - Modifications

D - Deletes

A - File or folder additions

I suggest you write an app to do this.

Comment: Does this work if you have no SCM enabled? I have tried writing this file and have verified that the one I am writing is identical to the output of an old job, but it will not show up in Jenkins.

Comment: No it will not work if there is no SCM enabled. In this case you can make jenkins checkout a empty svn folder with no files, and make it create a changelog.xml. Then edit it. Checking out a empty svn folder is not a big cost or time consuming. It's a workaround to get your work done.